# Run client socket.io on terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I was searching a if there is a way to run a node.js & socket.io client on terminal. My goal its that both client & server run on terminal. It work in a webpage but no in a terminal, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*terminal based chat application using socket.io and readline*

**Server :**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    
    let eventName = 'simple chat message';
    
    let broadcast = (msg) => socket.broadcast.emit(eventName, msg);
    
    socket.on(eventName, (msg, ackFn) => {
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
        // broadcast to other clients after 1.5 seconds
        setTimeout(broadcast, 1500, msg);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

> Server opens connection on http://localhost:3000
>
>  Receive messages from client and broadcast to other client

**Client :**

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin,  output: process.stdout });

rl.question('What\'s your name ? ', (name) => {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

    const sendMsg = () => {
        rl.question('> ', (reply) => {
            console.log(`Sending message: ${reply}`);
            socket.emit('simple chat message', `${name} says ${reply}`);
            sendMsg();
        });
    }

    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Sucessfully connected to server.');
        sendMsg();
    });

    socket.on('simple chat message', (message) => {
        console.log(message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Connection lost...')
    }); 
    
});
```

> Read text from terminal using `rl.question()`and send it to server using `socket.emit()`
>
>  send msg() is called recursively to read text from terminal and send it to server
>
>  `socket.on()` is used to receive messages from other clients

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65625575/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

Simple use socket.io-client from node process
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client

Answer (score 0):

You could use PhantomJS to run a headless browser on the terminal and have JavaScript for socket.io client in the page loaded to PhantomJS.